# Keys won't repeat, holding them down causes the screen to flash

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, screen

This is driving me nuts, and it started seemingly out of the blue.  While typing, if I hold down a key, it will not repeat, however, the cursor flickers in sync with the rate that the character would be repeated (leading me to believe that something is somehow intercepting my input). In the terminal, it's even worse, as the entire terminal flickers white (text color) when I type. yet more debilitating, sublime text goes COMPLETELY BLANK with each keystroke.   I've been through all the keyboard settings, turned everything off and on, completely uninstalled wine (purged and removed every trace I could find), restarted the computer countless times, and nothing has made a difference.

Please save me. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a HP Pavilion g6.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely NO CLUE why this worked, but pressing <kbd>prt sc</kbd> fixed the problem.  I don't know if I hit some incredibly obscure bug (I was taking a lot of screenshots earlier), or if there's physically something wrong with the key, or what, but if you're experiencing this problem, then go ahead and take a screenshot.